# How to scroll to a selected row in datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

```js
    switch (e.key) {
        case 'ArrowDown': { //arrow down

            await selectRow($tr.next());

            // }
            break;
        }
        case 'ArrowUp': { //arrow up

            await selectRow($tr.prev(), true);

            // }
            break;
        }
```

```js
const selectRow = async ($row, isprev = false, isclick = false) => {
    if ($row.length) {
        $f24Table = $('#lista-f24').DataTable();
        $f24Table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $row.addClass('selected');
        
        // const val = $($tr).find('td:eq(2)').text() + "|" + $($tr).find('td:eq(11)').text()
        const scambio = getRowData($row)
        $('#C_ROW').val(scambio)
        await anteprima(scambio)

         if (isclick === false) {
             $(".selected")[0].scrollIntoView(isprev);
         }
    }
}
```

when I press arrowkey up or down I move in my datatable
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8KpW.png)

I scroll in the datatable, but is scrolling the entire page too! why?

how I can scroll in the datatable to the selected row? I tried with different ways but nothing

edit: [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKrM8.png)

Comment: "*scrolling the entire page, why?*" - because that's what [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) does.   It could mean that your datatable doesn't have scrollbars - hard to tell from image.  You might need to write your own scroll into view

Comment: my datatable has the scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ScrollIntoView` on `.selected` directly, you can try using `ScrollTo()` on datatable as follows:

```
const selectRow = async ($row, isprev = false, isclick = false) => {
if ($row.length) {
    $f24Table = $('#lista-f24').DataTable();
    $f24Table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $row.addClass('selected');

    const scambio = getRowData($row);
    $('#C_ROW').val(scambio);
    await anteprima(scambio);

    if (isclick === false) {
        // use scrollTo on datatable
        $f24Table.scroller().scrollToRow($row);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thank you! the page now don't scroll, but i have the problem on the datatable that the scroll doesn't follow the selected row

Comment: see "Image2" to understand what i mean

Comment: sorry...i didnt see that...why? Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $f24Table.scroller is not a function